# Example of primitive substitution with two rationally independent eigenvalues?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

I am looking for an example of a primitive substitution $\sigma$, **not Pisot**, such that the associated subshift $X_\sigma$ has two irrational and rationally independent eigenvalues. Equivalently, a substitution $\sigma$ such that $X_\sigma$ has a minimal irrational rotation of the 2-dimensional torus as a factor.

There are well-known criteria for deciding whether a given complex number is an eigenvalue of $X_\sigma$, and a lot of examples of substitutive systems in the literature. But I couldn't build nor find an example of a substitution not Pisot with this kind of eiganvalues.